# how do I get numbers from this command

Tags: linux

I am doing a [geocache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocaching) in Arizona.
The Linux code for the coordinates are written as

```
-w-rw---x  r---wxrwx
```

any 2 can be substituted for a 9.

The false coordinates are N 33 27.000 W 112 20.000 so it should be close to
this. Is there an emulator I could use to get this calculated?

Comment: Do you need a few minutes to fix this up, or did you want to delete it and start fresh?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a puzzle. These are off topic, http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/is-solving-a-ctf-too-localized.

Comment: Though it's Unix related in context, it's of no value as a Q&A  to the U&L site.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was looking for an answer which I was supplied with. TY

Answer (score 2):

Those are file permissions. First, split them into groups of three.

```
-w- rw- --x  r-- -wx rwx
```

Now calculate the permissions in octal form.

```
-w- = 0 + 2 + 0 = 2
rw- = 4 + 2 + 0 = 6
--x = 0 + 0 + 1 = 1

r-- = 4 + 0 + 0 = 4
-wx = 0 + 2 + 1 = 3
rwx = 4 + 2 + 1 = 7
```

Now you have some numbers:

```
261 437
```

Hopefully that gets you closer to the cache.

Comment: See also: http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: good detective work on the answer, done one of these before?

Comment: I have. Geocaching used to be a hobby of mine.